# UISearchbar "Search Results Button" is only visible when input field is empty

Tags: ios, xcode, search, uisearchbar

Why is "Show Search Results Button" in UISearchBar is replaced by "x" when i am typing any text. In this case it is visible, clickable and `searchBarResultsListButtonClicked` is called only when the input field is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Show Search Results Button is on the bottom right keyboard

[image: Show Search Results Button]

Comment: no, it is not there. It is a button in the right corner of UISearchBar: https://ibb.co/BGmyTrV. But i already found the solution. I need to tap somewhere outside of the searchBar to make it out of focus. Than the button is visible again.